# Hashmaps password lock java

Tags: java

I have recently made a password lock thing in java to test my skills in learning hash maps. This is my code:

```
package com.Zach.Password;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r = new Random();
    HashMap<String, String> names = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> passwords = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> randNums = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter your name!!");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        if(names.containsKey(name))
        {
            int tries = 2;
            while(tries != 0)
            {
                if(tries != 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("What is your password?");
                    int normPassword = in.nextInt();

                    if(normPassword == passwords.get(name))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Welcome, " + name);
                        System.out.println("This is your random number:\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println("INCORRECT");
                }
                else if(tries == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("This account is locked! Unlock it by entering your random number!!");
                    int lockedRand = in.nextInt();
                    if(lockedRand == randNums.get(name))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Welcome, " + name);
                        System.out.println("This is your random number:\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println("INCORRECT");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int randNum = 1 + r.nextInt(99);
            randNums.put(name, randNum);
            names.put(name, name);
            System.out.println("Enter a password!!");
            int password = in.nextInt();
            passwords.put(name, password);
            System.out.println("Welcome, " + name);
            System.out.println("This is your random number:\n" + randNum);
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am not sure what the problem is, but whenever you enter a name it goes to the else statement for if names contains key... I do not stop the program and rerun... it just doesn't go down there.

Comment: To which 'else' statement? You have a few of them :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

Comment: @Solver They are populated within that `else` clause.

Comment: Didn't notice i had multiple i forgot to state which one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use replace `in.nextLine()` with `in.next();` for scanning the name. The `in.next();` blocks your application until the user input is submitted. The  `in.nextLine()` gives you just the rest of the current line and changes the position. Therefore it returns only the empty string if no input is given by the user.

Comment: THX Everyone for your help!! I ended up getting it to work!!